# Docker change Filesystem and Native Overlay Diff

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

What commands should I type to change below to:

```
  Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: <unknown>
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
```

to this:

```
  Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: false
```

in Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS 64bit Minimal

Comment: do you need to save your existing containers?  It looks like you're downgrading the features?

Comment: yes, I need to downgrade the features actually, any steps how to proceed?

Comment: If you need to change the storage implementation, generally you'll need to delete everything in `/var/lib/docker`.  Old containers and images won't be accessible, and there isn't a migration path.

Comment: that would be fine deleting everything, but then how to proceed from there onwards... I'm a newbie when it comes to docker